# Insomnia POST - 400 Bad Request - "Request body parsing: invalid character '%' looking for beginning of value"

Tags: web-scraping, curl, insomnia

I'm new to using insomnia. I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` error from a query.

I'm working in Ubuntu, using Firefox, and using the DevTools to identify a POST Request and Copy the value as cURL.  This is from gofundme.com.

I've been looking around and I can't find anything about this error in Insomnia, only in other API circumstances.  Apparently, I don't have the API vocabulary to successfully search for solutions to this error.  If someone could point me to a solution, or at least tell me more specifically where I should be looking, I would appreciate it.

I know this is a broad question.  Please let me know if you need more info.

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Request body parsing: invalid character '%' looking for beginning of value"
}
```

Full query.

```
https://e7phe9bb38-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.17.0)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20instantsearch.js%20(4.56.0)%3B%20react%20(18.2.0)%3B%20react-instantsearch%20(6.38.1)%3B%20react-instantsearch-hooks%20(6.38.1)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.13.0)&x-algolia-api-key=447d82ac9832ffcf05fb432dcb65bd08&x-algolia-application-id=E7PHE9BB38
```